# Bash OR operator not evaluating multiple variable

Tags: bash

The line in my bash script as follows is failing to evaluate multiple OR operators. It's check the first one then moving on

```
if [[ "${SERVER_NAME}" != $BITBUCKET || $CONFLUENCE || $CROWD || $JIRA || $JENKINS ]]; then
other code here...
fi
```

with a `bash -x` on the script I get this;

```
+ [[ crowd.server.com != code.server.com ]]
```

This is the `$BITBUCKET` variable and `$SERVER_NAME` is `crowd.server.com`
I need it to evaluate all the variables before moving on

Comment: This is not your script _failing_, it's your **brain**. If this equals that, or this is not null or that is not null or another thing is not null... etc - see the problem? It's your logic.

Comment: [A quick search on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bif-statement%5d%20multiple%20or) would have answered this for you also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to check one string on more strings. Do this:

```
if [[ ! "$SERVER_NAME" =~ ^($BITBUCKET|$CONFLUENCE|$CROWD|$JIRA|$JENKINS)$ ]]; then ...
```

Comment: That worked thanks, may I ask why? I'm trying to learn as much as I can. Even if you can point me to a web page. Thanks :-)

Comment: Everything about bash: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php , it would be long to explain in one comment. You've used `||` totally wrong.

Answer (score 7):

This is to be expected. When one of the terms of  `||` operator evaluates to `true`, the value of the whole sequence becomes `true`.

Try using `&&` operator, and use string comparison operator as many times as you have strings to compare.

Better yet, use `case` statement:

```
case "${SERVER_NAME}" in
    "$BITBUCKET" | "$CONFLUENCE" | "$CROWD" | "$JIRA" | "$JENKINS") ;; # do nothing for these servers
    *)
    # your original code here...
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: May I ask for an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to compare anything in the following or statements.
Consider this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "foo" || $1 == "bar" ]]; then
    echo "foo or bar"
else
    echo "not foo or bar"
fi
```

This looks like this upon execution:

```
./orTest.sh bar
foo or bar
./orTest.sh foo
foo or bar
./orTest.sh foobar
not foo or bar
```

In other words, what @Dmitry Grigoryev wrote:

> use string comparison operator as many times as you have strings to
>   compare

This is **wrong**:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 == "foo" || "bar" ]]; then
    echo "foo or bar"
else
    echo "not foo or bar"
fi
```

Examples:

```
/orTestFail.sh bar
foo or bar
./orTestFail.sh foo
foo or bar
./orTestFail.sh foobar
foo or bar
```